# Use custom log file for S.M.A.R.T errors with smartd?

Tags: login, smartctl, smart

As far as I understand smartd logs errors to syslog or sends them via mail.
But how can I setup smartd to log error messages into a custom log file?

Comment: Have a look in the manpage of `smartd` and search for `-l`.

Comment: Can't find anything here: https://linux.die.net/man/5/smartd.conf

Comment: Would be better to use the manpage of your local system to have a suitable manpage for your binary. So `man smartd` would be best, or [smartd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/smartd) online. Not `smartd.conf`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I found the right section now. I got confused with `smartd.conf` and `smartd` :-/